# Как работать с datetime в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Начал работать с датами и запоролся на моменте преобразования.
У меня в DF есть столбец с типом данных datetime64[ns], на основании которого мне нужно сделать второй столбец, но с изменённым представлением значения.
Вот так:

[image: Формат]

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Знаю, что задача элементарная и средствами Pandas решается на раз.

Возможно в ответе небольшой ликбез будет с другими подобными методами работы с datetame.Мне и другим польза будет. Есть книги, но там как-то глубоко заходят по работе с временными рядами, опуская элементарные задачки "как просто изменить то то". Аналитики уже знают возможные вопросы новичка. Задачу можно модифицировать для улучшения понимания других, если потребуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['New'] = df['DataDoc'].dt.strftime('%b %Y')
```

---

Работая в Jupyter или в iPython можно набрать:

```
df.DataDoc.dt.
```

и нажать кнопку “Tab”, чтобы увидеть все доступные методы для работы с временными данными - я часто пользовался данным методом во время изучения Pandas.